# Silverlight treeview with multiple TreeViewItemStyle

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, styles

Depending on bound item - I use different data templates to display data. Now I also need to modify behavior/style of treeview itself. Is it possible to switch style for items depending on object property? Right now it's only one specified: `ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource TreeViewItemStyleFolder}"`

I would like to create second style `TreeViewItemStyleDocument`

Current XAML (with custom style and template selector)

```
<sdk:TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" 
                      Grid.Row="1" 
                      Style="{StaticResource TreeViewStyle1}" 
                      ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource TreeViewItemStyleFolder}"
                      >
            <sdk:TreeView.ItemTemplate>
                <sdk:HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding SubItems}">
                    <DocumentManagement:DocumentTreeViewItemTemplateSelector 
                        Content="{Binding}">
                        <DocumentManagement:DocumentTreeViewItemTemplateSelector.FolderTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Grid>
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="24" />
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                    <!-- FOLDER ICON AND CAPTION -->
                                    <Image Source="{Binding IconSource}" Width="24" Height="24" />
                                    <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                                   Grid.Column="1" Margin="5,0"
                                   Text="{Binding Folder.FolderId}" FontSize="12" Foreground="#2C2C2C" />
                                </Grid>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </DocumentManagement:DocumentTreeViewItemTemplateSelector.FolderTemplate>
                        <DocumentManagement:DocumentTreeViewItemTemplateSelector.DocumentTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Grid>
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="24" />
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Orientation="Horizontal">
                                        <TextBlock FontSize="10" Foreground="#2C2C2C">
                                            <Run Text="Added by" />
                                            <Run Text="{Binding Document.MEMUser.UserName}" />
                                            <Run Text=" on " />
                                            <Run Text="{Binding CreatedOn, Converter={StaticResource DateTimeToStringConverter}}" />
                                        </TextBlock>                                        
                                        <!--BIND COMMANDS TO PARENT ViewModel to process operations-->
                                        <Button Content="Delete" Command="{Binding DataContext.DeleteCommand, ElementName=LayoutRoot}" CommandParameter="{Binding}" />
                                        <Button Content="Download" Command="{Binding DataContext.DownloadCommand, ElementName=LayoutRoot}" CommandParameter="{Binding}" />
                                    </StackPanel>
                                </Grid>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </DocumentManagement:DocumentTreeViewItemTemplateSelector.DocumentTemplate>
                    </DocumentManagement:DocumentTreeViewItemTemplateSelector>
                </sdk:HierarchicalDataTemplate>
            </sdk:TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        </sdk:TreeView>
```

**EDIT**:

Added triggers to switch ItemContainerStyle based on property but I think problem is that I'm using hieratchical data template. If I put breakpoint on `IsFolder` property - there is no source object.

```
<sdk:TreeView x:Name="DocumentsTreeView" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" 
                      Grid.Row="1" 
                      Style="{StaticResource TreeViewStyleTransparent}">
<!--            ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource TreeViewItemStyleFolders}"-->
            <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                <ei:DataTrigger Value="False" Binding="{Binding IsFolder}">
                    <ei:ChangePropertyAction TargetName="DocumentTreeView" PropertyName="ItemContainerStyle"                
                                             Value="{StaticResource TreeViewItemStyleFolders}" />
                </ei:DataTrigger>
                <ei:DataTrigger Value="True" Binding="{Binding IsFolder}">
                    <ei:ChangePropertyAction TargetName="DocumentTreeView" PropertyName="ItemContainerStyle" 
                                             Value="{StaticResource TreeViewItemStyleDocuments}" />
                </ei:DataTrigger>
            </i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <sdk:TreeView.ItemTemplate>
                <sdk:HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding SubItems}">

                    <DocumentManagement:DocumentTreeViewItemTemplateSelector 
                        Content="{Binding}">
                        <DocumentManagement:DocumentTreeViewItemTemplateSelector.FolderTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Grid>
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="24" />
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                    <!-- FOLDER ICON AND CAPTION -->
                                    <Image Source="{Binding IconSource}" Width="24" Height="24" />
                                    <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                                   Grid.Column="1" Margin="5,0"
                                   Text="{Binding Folder.FolderId}" FontSize="12" Foreground="#2C2C2C" />
                                </Grid>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </DocumentManagement:DocumentTreeViewItemTemplateSelector.FolderTemplate>
                        <DocumentManagement:DocumentTreeViewItemTemplateSelector.DocumentTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Grid>
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="24" />
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Orientation="Horizontal">
                                        <TextBlock FontSize="10" Foreground="#2C2C2C">
                                            <Run Text="Added by" />
                                            <Run Text="{Binding Document.MEMUser.UserName}" />
                                            <Run Text="on" />
                                            <Run Text="{Binding Document.CreatedOn, Converter={StaticResource DateTimeToStringConverter}}" />
                                        </TextBlock>                                        
                                        <!--BIND COMMANDS TO PARENT ViewModel to process operations-->
                                        <Button Content="Delete" Command="{Binding DataContext.DeleteCommand, ElementName=LayoutRoot}" CommandParameter="{Binding}" />
                                        <Button Content="Download" Command="{Binding DataContext.DownloadCommand, ElementName=LayoutRoot}" CommandParameter="{Binding}" />
                                    </StackPanel>
                                </Grid>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </DocumentManagement:DocumentTreeViewItemTemplateSelector.DocumentTemplate>
                    </DocumentManagement:DocumentTreeViewItemTemplateSelector>
                </sdk:HierarchicalDataTemplate>
            </sdk:TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        </sdk:TreeView>
```

Comment: What object property would determine the choice of Style Template? From what you describe you could set a trigger to change the property with a targetname to your treeview and just flip your ItemContainerStyle on the fly with a changepropertyaction / datatrigger possibly but wanted a little more info before I tried to provide some code.

Comment: Let's say it will be property `IsFolder` which when true should trigger one template and false will be another template. Keep in mind this is Silverlight, not WPF

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you want style to change dynamically based on a property value and you want this to be performed globally on everyitems on the page referencing the given style?

If that is the case I would suggest you looking into storyboards and states within Expression Blend. I do not see you mentioning Blend in your description. Are you using it? The treeview has many items that can be customized and some that are harder. I had an issue last week that my hyperlinks that were nested within a treeview could not effectively change the font color. I would probably been able to do it spending more time on the design but I changed the design intent instead.

The preview version of Blend for Silverlight 5 is free until June 2013 according to my install.
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=9503

Good luck,